# Blazor .Net 8 splash screen

Tags: blazor, splash-screen, .net-8.0

Before .Net 8, I could set a splash screen in the index.html file and   tag in the body part.
In the new templates there isn't a index.html file anymore.

I can find a lot of info about the old pre .Net 8 structures but not a lot about .Net 8 and the provided templates are very basic.

Does somebody know how to set a splash screen in the new project layout? (I'm using the global wasm option).

Before I had something like this in my index.html file (.net 7 and before)

```
<body>
<app id="app">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="p-5 bg-light border rounded-3 marginTop20px marginLeft20px marginRight20px mb-3 jumbotron">
            <h2>Please wait while the application is loading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</app>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

The application is a .Net core hosted project but with the global wasm option.

Comment: Why not use a custom component to do this?

Comment: Can you show what you had before.

Comment: Do you want a DotNetCore hosted solution or a Web Assembly Standalone solution?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp, if you can point me to a working example I would be very grateful, but I think the problem is that the components are not available when loading the application

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, I've added the answers to your questions in the original post above, thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to detect pre-rendering and show a `Splash` component before the client side SPA re-renders the page.

1. Add the *Blazr.RenderState.Server* Nuget package to the Server project.
2. Add the *Blazr.RenderState* services to the server.

```cs
builder.AddBlazrRenderStateServerServices();
```

1. Add the *Blazr.RenderState.WASM* Nuget package to the Client project.
2. Add the *Blazr.RenderState* services to the client.

```cs
builder.AddBlazrRenderStateWASMServices();
```

With these added, you have access to `IBlazrRenderStateService` and it's `IsPreRender` bool property in both server side and client side contexts.

Create a `Splash.razor` in the client project.

```cs
<div class="alert alert-primary m-5">
    BIG SPLASH
</div>
```

Modify `Router` to:

1. Display the `Splash` component if the page is pre-rendered.  Note the `return` to early exit.
2. Only do routing when we are in an active mode (in this case the WASM SPA has started).

```cs
@using Blazr.RenderState
@inject IBlazrRenderStateService RenderState

@if (RenderState.IsPreRender)
{
    <Splash />
    return;
}

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

This works for any page in the SPA.  *F5* on counter shows the splash screen.

Note: *Blazr.RenderState* is mine.  You can grab the code if you don't want to use the packages from here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.RenderState.

Comment: It doesn't happen a lot, but I'm very impressed. A big thank you for for your time and detailed explanation.
Just tested the example and works like a charm.
Nice that you also disclose that you are the developer of the Blazr nugets.