# Show loading html while Blazor Server app is initializing

Tags: blazor-server-side

When my app loads up for the first time theres a significant wait (probably due to security check and just normal blazor loading) where all I see is a white background.  Is there a way to show some loading html as soon as the page comes up?

I've tried wrapping the router in App.razor as well as a few other tricks I could think of, none of them show up until 5 or so seconds of the blank white screen.

Comment: Check this question and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261/blazor-net-8-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

Do not put anything in the App.razor. It will apply to all the pages. More importantly, it will not have access to the page specific function that is running longer.

A standard way of doing it:

```
    @page "/yourpageroute"
    
    <div>
       @if(isLoading)
       {
         <YourProgressElement/>
       }else{
    
             <YourContent/>
       }
    
    </div>
    
    
    @code{
       bool isLoading;
    
    
    
    protected override async OnInitializedAsyc()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        await yourLongMethodAsync();
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do this at the page/component level, i'm looking for how to do this before any specific page is hit, when the user has just hit enter in the browser url bar and the app loads a blank white background for 5-10 seconds

Comment: Has putting your imports at the bottom of _host.html worked? If your remote urls in <head> themselves take long time to load, then there is nothing you can do (probably in any framework). Honestly, it shouldn't take 5-10 seconds to load anything in blazor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a spinner on-load of the whole app right? Mayur's answer focuses on component-level. One way is by using BlazorFiddle's default template.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>BlazorFiddleProject</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.js"></script>    

    <style>
        app { }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<app>Loading...</app>

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>



namespace BlazorFiddleProject
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // Warning: IComponentsApplicationBuilder - not the original .NET 6.0 interface. This was done to make old saves work. 
        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
 

       app.AddComponent<App>("app");
    }
}
```

Another way is using the _Hosts.cshtml (or your custom entry-point razorpage or MVC view). You could show some plain HTML and CSS, which you delete as soon as your main app component loads.

Razor page entrypoint:

```
@page "/"
@namespace asfasf.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(MyBlazorApp)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />


<div class="spinner-that-is-always-spinning">

    <style>
        .spinner-that-is-always-spinning {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .spinner {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
```

MyBlazorApp.razor

```
protected override async OnInitializedAsyc()
{
    // remove class from div element with JSInterop
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("removeClassFunction", 
    "myClassParam"); // this function needs to be available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a div whit a class name loader_father

```
  <div class="loader_father">
     <div class="loader"></div>
 </div>
```

this class will have the style to create a loader

```
.loader_father {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    /*background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.5);*/ background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.loader {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border: 16px solid #c7c7c7; /*#f3f3f3*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #01395E; /*3498db*/
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

now in JS and JQUERY at the start of the page
i will start the loader

```
 $(".loader_father").show();
```

and on document ready i will hide it

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
 $(".loader_father").hide();
});
```

[Loader example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TfL.png)

Comment: This is not blazor specific and uses jquery, which I do not have access to in Blazor. I already know how to do this at the page/component level, i'm looking for how to do this before any specific page is hit, when the user has just hit enter in the browser url bar and the app loads a blank white background for 5-10 seconds